# How can I extract a value from an option of a given package in Latex?

Tags: r, algorithm, latex, listings

I have a template and I need to know if the option `language`, from the listings package, is `R`. Basically, I need to know if the listings package has the following statement:

```
{lstlisting}[language=R]
```

I can tell if the listings is selected:

```
$if(listings)$
\STATE
$endif$
```

But when I need to extract a value from the option `language`, I do the following and it doesn't work:

```
$if($listings-language$=R)$
\STATE
$endif$
```

I have tried `listings-language=R` and other things, but none of them worked.

Can someone help me? Thanks.